# Return specific HTTP response status in JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, httpresponse

I want to have a custom error code in my JSP, to prevent a special condition from happening:

```
boolean error;
// do error checking here

if (error) {
    throw new javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException(400);
}
```

However, this ends up throwing a 500 to the client, since the server interprets the exception as an internal issue. How can I send a status of 400 to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to send it through the response object:

```
<%
 response.sendError(418, "I'm a teapot" );
%>
```